# puppeteer navigation metrics: start and end time of each request/response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium, headless

I'm using this quick start code, allowing to go on a page with puppeteer headless.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const args = [
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-sandbox"
    ];
    const options = {
        args,
        headless: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.example.com/", {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
        timeout: 30000
    });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})()
```

I would like to have more information about the navigation:

can I get the **start** and the **end** time of each **request** and of each **response**.

Is there a function in puppeteer allowing to get these metrics?

for example the start time of the first request and the end time of the first response?
eventually of each **request** and each **response**...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **PerformanceObserver** you can get timing of each request by specifying entry type to "resource". Add each entry to object `window` and then evaluate it with puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const perfObsRunner = () => {
  window.resourceList = [];
  new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    list.getEntries().forEach((item) => {
      window.resourceList = [...window.resourceList, item.toJSON()]
    })
  }).observe({type: 'resource', buffered: true});
}


const getResourceTiming = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(perfObsRunner);
  await page.goto("https://pptr.dev/", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 30000 });
  const resource = await page.evaluate(() => ({ resource: window.resourceList }))

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
}
```

From response you can get information about request, like: startTime, duration, responseStart, responseEnd.
**Example response:**

```js
resource = [
    {
      "name": "https://pptr.dev/style.css",
      "entryType": "resource",
      "startTime": 55.9099999954924,
      "duration": 0,
      "initiatorType": "link",
      "nextHopProtocol": "h2",
      "workerStart": 0,
      "redirectStart": 0,
      "redirectEnd": 0,
      "fetchStart": 55.9099999954924,
      "domainLookupStart": 55.9099999954924,
      "domainLookupEnd": 55.9099999954924,
      "connectStart": 55.9099999954924,
      "connectEnd": 55.9099999954924,
      "secureConnectionStart": 55.9099999954924,
      "requestStart": 0,
      "responseStart": 0,
      "responseEnd": 55.9099999954924,
      "transferSize": 0,
      "encodedBodySize": 3704,
      "decodedBodySize": 14326,
      "serverTiming": [],
      "workerTiming": []
    },
    {
      "name": "https://pptr.dev/index.js",
      "entryType": "resource",
      "startTime": 56.08000000938773,
      "duration": 0,
      "initiatorType": "script",
      "nextHopProtocol": "h2",
      "workerStart": 0,
      "redirectStart": 0,
      "redirectEnd": 0,
      "fetchStart": 56.08000000938773,
      "domainLookupStart": 56.08000000938773,
      "domainLookupEnd": 56.08000000938773,
      "connectStart": 56.08000000938773,
      "connectEnd": 56.08000000938773,
      "secureConnectionStart": 56.08000000938773,
      "requestStart": 0,
      "responseStart": 0,
      "responseEnd": 56.08000000938773,
      "transferSize": 0,
      "encodedBodySize": 52861,
      "decodedBodySize": 149772,
      "serverTiming": [],
      "workerTiming": []
    },
    {
      "name": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/main/README.md",
      "entryType": "resource",
      "startTime": 98.98000000976026,
      "duration": 1.6949999844655395,
      "initiatorType": "fetch",
      "nextHopProtocol": "h2",
      "workerStart": 0,
      "redirectStart": 0,
      "redirectEnd": 0,
      "fetchStart": 98.98000000976026,
      "domainLookupStart": 0,
      "domainLookupEnd": 0,
      "connectStart": 0,
      "connectEnd": 0,
      "secureConnectionStart": 0,
      "requestStart": 0,
      "responseStart": 0,
      "responseEnd": 100.6749999942258,
      "transferSize": 0,
      "encodedBodySize": 0,
      "decodedBodySize": 0,
      "serverTiming": [],
      "workerTiming": []
    },
]
```